# Capturing touches in UIApplication and calling a function in ViewController causing error

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiapplication, uievent

I have the below Swift 2 code set up that captures all touches across the whole app. It alerts when touches are occurring and when touches have stopped.

I am wanting to access two functions in another view controller named `myVC` when touches are occurring and when they’ve stopped, calling function one `funcOne()` and function two `funcTwo()`. However I continuously get an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. It seems whenever `myVC` is called, it causes errors.

How can I achieve calling a function on the ViewController without errors and please depending on when the app is receiving or not receiving any touch events in Swift 2 please?

`main.swift` file:

```
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

`UIApplication.swift` file:

```
import UIKit

@objc(MyApplication)

class MyApplication: UIApplication {

var myVC: ViewController!

    override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent) {

        if event.type != .Touches {
            super.sendEvent(event)
            return
        }

        var touchesStarted = false
        if let touches = event.allTouches() {
            for touch in touches.enumerate() {
                if touch.element.phase != .Cancelled && touch.element.phase != .Ended {
                    touchesStarted = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if touchesStarted {
    myVC.funcOne()  // Call function one on ViewController
        } else {
    myVC.funcTwo() // Call function two on ViewController
        }

        super.sendEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying

```
 var myVC: ViewController!
```

but you are never *setting* that variable `myVC` to any value (i.e. an existing ViewController instance). Thus it is always `nil`, and so when you refer to it in your code, you crash.

My advice would be that this view controller, in its own `viewDidLoad`, should say

```
(UIApplication.sharedApplication() as MyApplication).myVC = self
```

Comment: By the way, what you're doing is a really bad idea, and it's totally unnecessary. You could more safely intervene in touch handling by subclassing UIWindow instead of UIApplication, or even better, intervene at the level of the view controller by means of an invisible view in front of everything.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. How can I set a variable for myVC to a value?

Comment: I've tried `UIWindow`, but it doesn't work for all gestures and touches combined. `UIApplication` does work however using `print` to test it. However I need to set a function going in the ViewController.

Comment: You say `myVC = theViewController`. But getting a reference to the actual view controller is your problem; I have no notion of where it is in your view controller hierarchy — it's _your_ app! My advice would be that the view controller itself in its own `viewDidLoad` should do this, since it can see the application: `(UIApplication.sharedApplication() as MyApplication).myVC = self`

Comment: Huzzah! Progress, all is working. Thank you very kindly!

Comment: PS @matt I'm interested to understand a bit more about why doing this is a really bad idea and the safety issues around it if you could please elaborate? I did at one point consider an invisible uiview, but didn't know exactly how to achieve that.